# Large db table with many rows or many columns

Tags: sql-server, database

I have tried to have a normalized table design. The problem (maybe) is that we are generating a lot of data, and therefore a lot of rows. Currently the database is increasing in size by 0,25 GB per day.

The main tables are Samples an Boxes. There's a one-to-many relation from Samples to Boxes. 
Sample table:

```
ID | Timestamp | CamId
```

Boxes table:

```
ID | SampleID | Volume | ...
```

We analyse 19 samples each 5 seconds, and each sample on avg has 7 boxes. That's 19*7*12 = 1596 boxes each minute and 1596*60*24 = 2,298,240 rows in Boxes table each day on avg.

This setup might run for months. At this time the Boxes table has about 25 million rows.

Quistion is; should i be worried about database size, table size and table design with so much data?

Or should I have a table like

```
ID | SampleID | CamId | Volume1 | Volume2 | ... | Volume9 | ...
```

Comment: What indexes have you on the tables in question?

Comment: @TT. I have primary keys on ID columns. On Samples I have a unique multi column constraint on Timestamp and CamId. On Boxes I also have a multi column constraint on SampleId and another column foreign key column not shown

Comment: Read up on how to design your databases with indexes to speed up querying. For instance this: [SQL Server Index Design Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-index-design-guide).

Comment: Then also you might want to read up on table paritioning, seeing as you will have a huge amount of rows and thus table size. For instance this: [SQL Server Table Partitioning: Resources](https://www.brentozar.com/sql/table-partitioning-resources/).

Comment: I would go with Partitioning,if you are using enterprise edition(In SQL2016,this restriction has been removed,now partition is not limited to only enterprise edition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the validity of your data, you could implement a purge of your data.
What I mean is: do you really need data from days ago, months ago, years ago? If you have a time limit of use for your data, purge them and your data table should stop growing (or likely) after a set amount of time.

This way you wouldn't need to care that much about either architecture for the sake of size.

Otherwise the answer is yes, you should care. Separate notions in a lot of tables could give you a good tweak on performance but maybe won't be sufficient in terms of access time after a long time. Consider looking at NoSQL solutions or alike in order to store heavy rows.

Comment: We are still discussing for how long data is needed. So some form of purging of data might be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

There is one simple rule: **Whenever you think you have to put a number to a column's name you probably need a related table**.

The amount of data will be roughly the same, no wins here.

I'd try to partition the table. AFAIK this feature was bound to the Enterprise Editions, but - according to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-supported-features-for-sql-server-2016) - with SQL Server 2016 SP1 table and index partitioning is coming down even to Express!

The main question is: **What are you going to do with this data?**

If you have to run analytical scripts over *everything*, there won't be a much better hint than *buy better hardware*.
If your needs refer to *data of the last 3 weeks* you will be fine off with partitioning.

If you cannot use this feature yet (due to your Server's version), you can create an archive table and move older data into this table in regular jobs. A `UNION ALL` view would still allow to grab the whole lot. With `SCHEMA BINDING` you might even get the advantages of *indexed views*.

In this case it is clever, to hold your working data in your fastest drive and put the archive table in a separate file on a large storage somewhere else.

Comment: Partition sounds like a good idea. And if it is available in 2016 Express then that's super! Do you have and idea on how it will effect performance?

Comment: @smok You ask *how it will effect performance*... This depends on what you are doing... The general idea is the same, as I've described with the archive table. The advantage is, that SQL Server will do the hard work automatically and will use this information for optimized statistics and indexing... If your working data is a small set (let's say *the last 3 months*), while you need the whole set just now and then, the effect will be remarkeable.

Answer (score 0):

Question is, should i be worried about database size, table size and table design with so much data?

My answer is `YES:`

```
1. A huge amount of data(daily) should affect your storage in hardware part.
2. Table normalized is a must mostly if you are storing bytes or images.
```